# jquery getting trigger function to fire with certain mouse coords on jquery ui slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I wont bother with the background of the project but I am having issues getting a jquery ui slider to register a click using the trigger function.

Basically design dictates that a label (or any dom element) sits on top of the slider. This has to be donw by tweaking that elements z-index in css. However, you then obviosuly cant click the slider as this element is on top of, and thus in the way, and nothing registers.

I have set up a fiddle here which helps detail the issue. Basiucally I wont both sliders to act the same functionally (with or without the label).

http://jsfiddle.net/adrianjacob/5StND/

js for ref:

```
$("ul > li").each(function () {

    $(this).children('span').slider({
        value: 100,
        min: 0,
        max: 500,
        step: 25
    });

    $(this).on('click', 'label', function (e) {
        var evt = {
            'type': 'click',
            'pageX': e.pageX,
            'pageY': e.pageY
        };
        $(this).siblings('span.ui-slider').trigger(evt);
    });

});
```

Cheers,
Adi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that inserts the span element within the handle, so it stays 'attached' to the handle.

```
$(this).children('span')
    .slider({
        value: 100,
        min: 0,
        max: 500,
        step: 25
    })
    .siblings("label")
        .appendTo($(this).find(".ui-slider-handle"))
;
```

Here's a [**link to jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/martyk/5StND/5/)